# ES6, return a list of string separated by comma by an array of objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have some objects

```
var officers = [
  { id: 20, name: 'Captain Piett' },
  { id: 24, name: 'General Veers' },
  { id: 56, name: 'Admiral Ozzel' },
  { id: 88, name: 'Commander Jerjerrod' }
];
```

I need to return "20","24","56","88"

Now I'm using

```
const ids = officers.map(officer => officer.id);
```

but it return me an array of course.

What's the most efficient way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to return array of string with `""` and then use `join()`

```js
var officers = [
  { id: 20, name: 'Captain Piett' },
  { id: 24, name: 'General Veers' },
  { id: 56, name: 'Admiral Ozzel' },
  { id: 88, name: 'Commander Jerjerrod' }
];

const res = officers.map(x => `"${x.id}"`).join()

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can surround by quotes on map and then call Array.join.

```
const ids = officers.map(officer => '"' + officer.id + '"').join();
```

Answer (score 0):

**What's the most efficient way?**

Array.map creates each time a new function and calls it, thats not efficient.

The most efficient way is to use plain for-loops:

```
var res = '';
for(let {id} in officers){ 
 res+=....
}
```

**But** now you would create each time a new string (`res+=...`).
Thats absolutely ok if you don't have to handle alot of strings, but in the case you do you may want to switch to arrays and join it into a string at the end.